# Undoing a dynamic update

Tags: interaction-design, checkout

We have a checkout process which follows this sequence:

1. choose between two possible products
2. select a duration for the chosen product
3. enter payment details
4. your receipt

We want to compress steps 1 and 2 into one page, where once the user chooses product A or product B there is a dynamic change in the page. As opposed to taking the user to a new page.

It would look something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9ZGbi.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

However ... once a user chooses one of the membership types we don't have an obvious way for the user to go back that one step.

**Any suggestions on how a user could go back to deciding between A vs B?**

Comment: When you say membership type, you mean between Alpha and Beta membership? Or when they click the buy button?

Comment: @Majed Alpha vs Beta. The buy buttons is simply for the duration.

Answer (score 1):

You could use 2 [accordions](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/) on the 1st step. Once the user chooses the membership type, the accordion will expand and the details will show. Clicking it again will collapse the details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 2x4 matrix, with Y-axis the product and X-axis the duration.

EDIT :
Roughly something like this :
When a checkbox is selected all other checkboxes are unselected.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHZ6ay.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>